# Disocrd bot simple flag game

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, pycord

i want to made simple flag game in my bot

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View
import random
import asyncio

# Initialize intents for the Discord bot.
intents = discord.Intents.default()

# Initialize the bot.
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)

# Dictionary of flags in the format name: emoji.
flags = {
    "Poland": "",
    "Germany": "",
    "France": "",
    "Italy": "",
    "Spain": "",
    "United Kingdom": "",
    "Sweden": "",
    "Norway": "",
    "Japan": "",
    "China": "",
    "Canada": "",
    "Australia": "",
    "Russia": "",
    "Brazil": "",
    "Argentina": "",
    "India": "",
    "Greece": "",
    "Egypt": "",
    "Turkey": "",
    "South Africa": "",
}

# Function called when the bot is ready.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    """Set the bot's status to "Under Maintenance" and Do Not Disturb mode."""
    print("Bot is running...")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing,
                                                                                   name="Under Maintenance"))

# Slash command "/help" displaying the list of available commands.
@bot.slash_command(name='help', description='Show a list of available commands')
async def help(ctx):
    """Show a list of available commands."""
    embed_help = discord.Embed(title='Available Commands', description='')
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed_help)

# Slash command "/ping" displaying the bot's latency.
@bot.slash_command(name='ping', description='Show the bot\'s ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    """Show the bot's ping."""
    latency = round(bot.latency)
    embed_ping = discord.Embed(title=f'Pong! My latency is {latency}ms', color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed_ping)

@bot.slash_command(name='flags', description='Play a flag guessing game')
async def flag_game(ctx):
    """Start a flag guessing game."""
    # Randomly select a flag from the list.
    random_flag = random.choice(list(flags.keys()))

    # Send a "Drawing..." message with an emoji.
    drawing_message = await ctx.send("Drawing... <a:random_:966715531216429076>")
    await ctx.respond("Flag Game Started")

    # Wait for 3 seconds.
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    # Edit the message to show the flag.
    flag_emoji = flags[random_flag]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Flag Game', description=f"Here is the flag of one of the countries. What is the name of this country?")
    embed.add_field(name="Flag:", value=flag_emoji, inline=False)
    await drawing_message.edit(content=None, embed=embed)

    # Wait for the user's response.
    try:
        response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30.0)

        # Check the response, ignoring case.
        if response.content.lower() == random_flag.lower():
            await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! Correct answer. It's the flag of {random_flag}.")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Sorry, that's not the correct answer. The correct answer is {random_flag}.")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Time for a response has expired. Game over.")

# Slash command "/invite" sending an invite link to the bot.
@bot.slash_command(name='invite', description='Send a bot invite link')
async def invite(ctx):
    """Send a bot invite link."""
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Add me!",
        description="Click here to add me to your server.",
        color=discord.Color.green(),
    )

    # Create a button with the invite link.
    invite_button = Button(
        style=discord.ButtonStyle.link,
        label="Add me!",
        emoji="<:arrow_:966715437662478388>",
        url="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&permissions=8&scope=bot",
    )

    # Create a view and add the button to it.
    view = View()
    view.add_item(invite_button)

    # Send the message with the embedded button.
    await ctx.respond(embed=embed, view=view)

# Run the bot with your token.
bot.run("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN")
```

[image]

(I Translated this from Polish language)
This is a simple game in disocrd.py "Guess The Flag" when you write /flags you must guess flag of the country and in dont works (at a picture)

This game is rare to find in bot so i can't find an answer
and im newbie in disocrd.py
thanks for every help

Answer (score 0):

I did not do too much but for me **(in discord.py 2.3.2)** it works now.

```
flags = {
    "Poland": "",
    "Germany": "",
    "France": "",
    "Italy": "",
    "Spain": "",
    "United Kingdom": "",
    "Sweden": "",
    "Norway": "",
    "Japan": "",
    "China": "",
    "Canada": "",
    "Australia": "",
    "Russia": "",
    "Brazil": "",
    "Argentina": "",
    "India": "",
    "Greece": "",
    "Egypt": "",
    "Turkey": "",
    "South Africa": "",
}

@bot.command(name='flags', description='Play a flag guessing game')
async def flag_game(ctx:commands.Context):
    """Start a flag guessing game."""
    # Randomly select a flag from the list.
    random_flag = random.choice(list(flags.keys()))

    # Send a "Drawing..." message with an emoji.
    drawing_message = await ctx.send("Drawing... :checkered_flag:")
    await ctx.reply("Flag Game Started")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    # Wait for 3 seconds.
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    # Edit the message to show the flag.
    flag_emoji = flags[random_flag]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Flag Game', description=f"Here is the flag of one of the countries. What is the name of this country?")
    embed.add_field(name="Flag:", value=flag_emoji, inline=False)
    await drawing_message.edit(content=None, embed=embed)

    # Wait for the user's response.
    try:
        response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30.0)

        # Check the response, ignoring case.
        if response.content.lower() == random_flag.lower():
            await ctx.send(f"Congratulations! Correct answer. It's the flag of {random_flag}.")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Sorry, that's not the correct answer. The correct answer is {random_flag}.")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Time for a response has expired. Game over.")
```

Changes:
Defined the type of ctx `ctx:commands.Context`

`await ctx.response` to `await ctx.reply`

`await ctx.channel.purge` put after the reply

`"Drawing... <a:random_:966715531216429076>"` to `"Drawing... :checkered_flag"`

Made the whole command to `@bot.command()`

That's it.